# MPI Runtime environment issue

Tags: mpi

I am trying to run below program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<mpi.h>

main(int argc, char **argv){
      int size, myrank;
      MPI_init(NULL, NULL);
      MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
      MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myrank);
      printf("My rank is\n",myrank);
}
```

command to compile and run:

```
mpicc hello.c
mpirun -np 4 a.out
```

Expected Output:

```
My rank is 0
My rank is 1
My rank is 2
My rank is 3
```

Actual Output:

```
My rank is 0
My rank is 0
My rank is 0
My rank is 0
```

Why did I get the output with all ranks equal to zero, and what should I do to 
get the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line

```
printf("My rank is\n",myrank);
```

is missing `%d`:

```
printf("My rank is %d\n",myrank);
```

Furthermore, `MPI_init` should be `MPI_Init`, and you are missing a `MPI_Finalize` statement.

Apart from that, make sure that  `a.out` that you run is really the one you think it is, for instance using

```
mpirun -np 4 ./a.out
```

rather than

```
mpirun -np 4 a.out
```

and make sure that both `mpicc` and `mpirun` come from the same implementation : OpenMPI, IntelMPI, MPich, etc, do not like to mix commands from one another.

Comment: I don't think that what the OP shows here is the actual program code. `printf()` won't output any number given the current format string and also a call to `MPI_Finalize()` is missing, therefore the MPI job will terminate abnormally the very moment one rank returns from `main`.